# How to store a binary grid using a float variable

Tags: binary, integer, numbers, save, extract

This is not connected to any particular programming language, I'm trying to look for the most efficient way to store a binary grid (It will look like this...)

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Into an int with a limit of 9,999,999
So each "1" Have a Boolean of true/false a.k.a "1" or "0" state so it can be displayed as also

```
1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

All this is expected to be stored in an int so it can be transformed binary into digits.

So at the end of the day, I should be able to first set a binary grid then turn the binary grid into digits where I can store them into a variable, And then be able to extract them after from the variable back to the binary grid.

And also to answer any question related to why I just don't simply use an array or anything in relation, Well basically this is the only way the engine lets me store things to then extract them later.

Things I try: I already know I can store things within the digit system, What I lack is getting the most out of it, right now I can store 23 Bits which means that I got to get a binary grid that looks like this

```
 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1
```

And remember this is having the limit of 9,999,999
I found out the system can have it from -9,999,999 to 9,999,999.

Another thing is that the limit of 9,999,999 is all-around any function so adding 9,999,999 + 9,999,999 is out of the question for that limitation.

So I'm going to add all the relevant details:

- I can only use digits to store data in a variable.
- The limit of the digits go only to 9,999,999
- If I were to use floats it will have to be < 999,999.00 note that the limit on the float is 2 decimal points (0.00)
- If I want, I can use multiple variables in terms that have more capacity
- What I'm looking for is to try to get the most amount of bits out of the digits limit in the variable.

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: How big will your array be at most? If your array will have less than 32 (or 64) elements in total, a simple bit indexing will do.

Comment: Well I have tried finding the most efficient way to store it by finding other ways to turn it into a simple binary, another way to think of it is like a Minecraft type scene where these "Binary grids" are chunks and they are loaded when you get to them but for that to happen they have to be stored before being deleted, so where I'm failing at the moment is the store the data part.

Comment: Storing a number of bits in an int is not so difficult, but depends on your concrete requirements. How big is your array going to be? Also, why do you have the limit of 9,999,999? The limit of a 32-bit number is 4,294,967,295.

Comment: @PMF the number that is the limit doesn't really matter, in the engine is basically used for multiple things like keeping score, or points, etc. But as I'm only trying to store things in it so basically the higher I can store something in it the better.

Comment: @PMF But because the limit of is 9,999,999 this means that 
(9,999,999 < The 32-bit number)
So storing big thing I guess is out of the question?
Well that why I'm here to see if there still a possibility or a compromise.
Note: On this variable you can also set it with a minimum of -9,999,999 to a max of 9,999,999. Is there could be a way to turn the negative volues to turn it into extra space could it be possible? This means adding 9,999,999 + 9,999,999 to get a higher value.

Comment: I think you should get your API fixed. A storage that only accepts integer values -9,999,999 to 9,999,999 sounds dubious in itself, let alone if that's the only type of objects  you can store.

Comment: @PMF Yeah your right I think the same but that is how the engine works, I can't even use strings, I can use floats but is not trusting at numbers 8,000,000 >.
The good side is that I can use more than 100+ variables.
Another way to think of this engine is basically getting games to fit around 10Mb of storage or something

Comment: @PMF So is no API issue or anything is how the developer decided it should act like ( I personally don't use the engine that often, But is fun putting things that aren't expected the engine to run like right now a storage system.)

Comment: You've solved most of the issues already, I was just going to write almost the same thing as what you added to your question. The sign is just one extra bit you get, not more.

Comment: floats are perfectly legitimate places to store bits. An IEEE-754 binary64 float can hold 52-bit integers exactly.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Another thing is it only has a 2 decimal point. so basically it will be below the 16 binary that it will into (So I'm not able to have 3 decimals like 29.432 only 2 decimals like 12.32) So with that in mind, that basically limit it to anything below 16bit?

Comment: I think you're being too circumspect with the details of your environment. Please add all the relevant details to your question so we don't have to go through these iterations of "How about this? No, that won't work because of < *new details ...* > "

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Updated. That should clear some things up.